# Stop ajax request called from a method (ES6)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-class

I have a class that does some ajax call

```
export default class AjaxCall {
  constructor(options) {
    // some options
  }

  ajax(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.ajax(options).done(resolve).fail(reject);
    });
  }

  doAjax() {
    return this.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      ...
  }
}
```

And I am calling this ajax in another file

```
import AjaxCall from './ajax';

$(function() {
  const options = {...};

  const ajaxCall = new AjaxCall(options);

  $('.button-start').on('click', function() {
    ajaxCall.doAjax(options ...);
  });

});
```

So what I am wondering is if it is possible to have a method (or some other way), that will stop that ajax call, such that I can have another button that will call this method on click.

I know that there is `xhr.abort()` but that is used when `xhr` is a variable set to the ajax call.

Comment: Why wrap the `jqXHR` in a promise? It's already promise-like and if you simply return it from your method, you can use the `.abort()` method.

Comment: Well I wanted it to be a real Promise, don't think I have any special reason tbh

Comment: You would need to store a reference to your `$.ajax` so you can `.abort()` on it. This code is wack.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply return the `jqXHR` object instead of wrapping it in a `Promise`.

```
ajax(options) {
  return $.ajax(options);
};
```

This way, you have access to the `abort` method, eg

```
let jqXHR = ajaxCall.doAjax(options ...)
if (someAbortReason) {
  jqXHR.abort()
}
```

---

FYI...

> The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information).

One important thing to note however is that jQuery only added the [`catch`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/) method to its *Deferred* object API in v3.0

Comment: Hmm I will try this. I was aware that it has Promise like behavior, but if it has the `catch` method I can bundle jQuery 3 on build (I'm using webpack).